# Cannot load scene from asset bundle in standalone

Tags: unity-game-engine

Two scenes I am switching between both are from asset bundles used by this code. The code is working in Editor but not in the build. What I am missing?

```
  public IEnumerator LoadSceneBundle(string assetBundleSceneName, string orignialName) {

        //url = "file://" + Application.dataPath + "/AssetBundles/" + assetBundleSceneName + ".unity3d";
        Debug.Log(Application.dataPath);
        //this code for build
        newExtractedPath = Application.dataPath;
        //this code for runtime
        //newExtractedPath = Application.dataPath.Substring(0, Application.dataPath.Length - 7);
        Debug.Log(newExtractedPath  +" :: newExtractedPath");
        //url = "file://" + Application.dataPath + "/AssetBundles/" + assetBundleSceneName + ".unity3d";
        url = "file://" + newExtractedPath + "/AssetBundles/" + assetBundleSceneName + ".unity3d";
        Debug.Log("scene load url : " + url);
        using (WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload(url,1)){
            yield return www;
            if (www.error != null) {
                throw new Exception("WWW download had an error : " + url + " " + www.error);
                //Debug.Log("");
            }

            AssetBundle ab = www.assetBundle;
            Debug.Log(www.assetBundle.mainAsset);

            ab.LoadAll();
            Application.LoadLevel(originalName);
            ab.Unload(false);
        }
    }
```

After deployment, I made an AssetsBundle folder and placed my assetbundle scene files, but it isn't working. All was in vain.

Answer (score 1):

Your path seems wrong. If you are embedding the asset bundles into your game, you should put them under the StreamingAssets folder so they'll end up in the game build. According to [the documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html):

> Any files placed in a folder called StreamingAssets in a Unity project will be copied verbatim to a particular folder on the target machine.

So do that and use `Application.streamingAssetsPath` to form your path and you should be able to use `WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload` to get them.

Comment: So the standard way is to place assetbundle in streamingAsset Folder and this folder will deploy automatically as we made standalone build? right?

Comment: Yes. Create the folder inside the _Assets_ folder (`Assets/StreamingAssets/`)

Comment: +thanks for this valuable information but this is were not the problem !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load an asset bundle for a standalone Unity Application, I think you would be better served by AssetBundle.CreateFromFile() - which is simpler and faster.  Only catch is that the asset bundle can't be compressed.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.CreateFromFile.html